# Looking for solution to intercept baseclass inherited method using Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring

I am looking for solution to intercept parent class inherited method which is called from child another method.
Parent class `LoggerException` class having `handleException` method and I am calling this method from its child class `SubLoggerException`'s method `getException`,
trying to intercept inherited method `handleException` from aspect programming

```
public class LoggerException{

    public String handleException(Exception genericException) {

         System.out.println("enter in LoggerException ");
         return "success";
      }

    }



  public class SubLoggerException extends LoggerException{

    public void getException(){
        handleException(null);
    }
    }
       @Aspect
    public class ErrorNotificationLogger {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ErrorNotificationLogger.class);

    @Around("setterMethod(o)")
    public Object markedMethodsAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Object o) throws Throwable {
     System.out.println(" ****** Around Advice called ***************** ");
     return null;

     }

    //@Pointcut("execution(* com.aop.LoggerException+.handleException(..)) && target(com.aop.SubLoggerException)")
    //@Pointcut("execution(* com.aop.LoggerException+.handleException(..)) && this(o)")
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.aop.LoggerException.handleException(..)) && this(o)")
    public void setterMethod(Object o) {}
}



    public class App extends AbstractService{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                new String[] { "Spring-Customer.xml" });

        SubLoggerException  cust = (SubLoggerException)appContext.getBean("subLoggerExceptionBean");


        System.out.println("*************************");

        cust.getException();
        System.out.println("*************************");
        try {
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling another instance method from a Spring AOP proxy, these calls are not intercepted. The reason is that the actual execution of an intercepted method always ocurrs at the original bean (the proxy's target bean). As a consequence the other method will neven be called on the proxy object, but always on the target bean itself. What you need is a way to access the proxy from inside the target bean and then call the method on the proxy. You can get the proxy this way:

```
 AopContext.currentProxy()
```

So, what you have to do is:

```
 public void getException(){
     ((LoggerException)AopContext.currentProxy).handleException(null);
 }
```

But consider that the proxy must be accessible if this shall work. This can be configured in your appContext.xml:

```
 <aop:aspectj-autoproxy expose-proxy="true"/>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Patrick really appreciate your prompt reply, yes Its help, I changed configuration as

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" expose-proxy="true"/>

But Is there is way to execute advice without changing in subclass method ?

Comment: You're welcome, Shweta. As far as I know there's no other possibility in Spring AOP. As mentioned in my post, you need a way to call the superclass method on the Spring proxy rather than on the target bean itself.   But I agree with you that this doesn't look very nice, maybe Spring will offer more elegant ways in the future.